# "Error: No builder configured" issue `npm run storybook`

Tags: javascript, npm, storybook

I get this error when trying to `npm run storybook` after, what appears to be, a successful installation of the Alpha 7.

Where can I start to look for debugging this?

[image]

Comment: did you specify a framework when you did `storybook init`? i.e. next would be `npx storybook@next init`

Comment: check your main.js for  `{ framework: { name: "@storybook/nextjs" } }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `.storybook/main.js` file was empty

Follow [Storybook builders installation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/overview) and configure main.js file for [webpack](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack) or [vite](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/vite) - whatever you are using

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to 7, and automatically got webpack5. When I switched to vite, I forgot to install the `vite` package, so was stuck with this error. After installing, it went away.